# Remove duplicate polygons in a single layer using ogr2ogr?

Tags: ogr2ogr, spatialite, duplication

I have a spatialite database file containing buildings within a country as multipolygons. While trying to use QGIS to delete these duplicate features, QGIS keeps on crashing due to the millions of buildings within the layer. So I am trying to find an command line solution using ogr2ogr but cannot find any info. What would be the syntax to do such a task?

Comment: I guess that duplicate buildings have still different feature IDs, is it true?

Comment: The data was downloaded from OSM, so I guess they have different IDs. I simply want to ensure that duplicate geometries are removed in the layer.